# getting a 500 error when trying to update http-mock in ember

Tags: ember.js, express, put, ember-cli

I'm getting a 500 server error in the console when trying to update a record from an http-mock generated in ember-cli.

Here is what I'm trying to do

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('user', params.pin);
},
actions: {
    check_out: function(checkedUser) {
        var model = this.modelFor(this.routeName);

        model.set('checked_in',false);

        model.save().then(function(){
            self.transitionTo('volunteer-check-out-success');
        });
    }
}
```

but I'm receiving this error in the console

```
PUT http://localhost:4200/api/users/2 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

the get request works just fine so it's odd that I'm getting 500 with the put request.

Does anyone have a good overview of how to use http-mock? Maybe even in it's earlier stages before it was called http-mock? I'm still a little confused on how this works inside of ember-cli and documentation and examples are kind of sparse from what I've been finding. And I think reading up on some info on how this works in theory would help me troubleshoot it on my own.

UPDATE:

Here is the server implementation, I have this variable that the get request is reading from

```
var USERS = [
{
  "id": 1,
  "checked_in": false,
  "pin": 1234,
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "email": "email@example.com",
  "phone": 8436376960
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "checked_in": false,
  "pin": 5678,
  "first_name": "Jane",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "email": "email@example.org",
  "phone": 8436375738
}
];
```

And my put route handler like so

```
usersRouter.put('/:id', function(req, res) {
var id = req.params.id;
var user = USERS.filter(function(user) {
  return user.id.toString() == id;
})[0];

user.checked_in = req.body.checked_in;
user.pin = req.body.pin;
user.first_name = req.body.first_name;
user.last_name = req.body.last_name;
user.email = req.body.email;
user.phone = req.body.phone;

return res.send(user);
});
```

Comment: Since the error is on the API side, you should show the server implementation.

Comment: I added the server implementation for the put request

Answer (score 1):

http://expressjs.com/api.html

I've never used it, but if it's anything like the majority of the ajax mocking tools out there, you'll need to setup routes to handle different endpoints and also to handle different verbs (GET/POST).

In your case I'd guess your original route setup handles the `/projects/` endpoint for the `GET` verb, whereas when you save it `